# Do these validation statements contradict?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

On page 94 of *Agile Web Development with Rails 4* by Sam Ruby I found the following code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  }
  # other validations...
end
```

My understanding of it is that `:image_url, presence: true` is the statement requiring for the text field `image_url` to not be left blank which to my understanding contradicts with `:image_url, allow_blank: true`.

Is that in fact a contradiction and therefore an error in the book or is there an error in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read page 84 of the book he specifically says...

> Note that we used the allow_blank option to avoid getting multiple
>   error messages when the field is blank.

So it's there simply to ensure only ONE error is added to the object.errors on a blank condition.  If you didn't specify "allow blank" then you would get both "cannot be blank" and "must be gif/jpg/png" messages which would actually be unclear to the end user.  "cannot be blank" is sufficient.

Which is to say, the match-format error we allow it to happily ignore blank entries because we know they're caught by the other validation.